# Get intersect of two queries in MongoDB with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following dataset and I need to extract the `regno` of any document with `dormant` `true` before March 31st 2018, and `dormant` `false` after March 31st 2020. I am performing my querying in pymongo.

```
{
_id : "uniqueid1",
date: "2017-05-30",
dormant: true,
regno: "0001"
}
{
_id : "uniqueid2",
date: "2017-05-30",
dormant: true,
regno: "0002"
}
{
_id : "uniqueid3",
date: "2017-05-30",
dormant: false,
regno: "0003"
}
{
_id : "uniqueid4",
date: "2021-05-30",
dormant: false,
regno: "0001"
}
{
_id : "uniqueid5",
date: "2021-05-30",
dormant: true,
regno: "0002"
}
{
_id : "uniqueid6",
date: "2021-05-30",
dormant: false,
regno: "0004"
}
```

The following python code gets me two queries, which I can `or` together to get a single list of entries which match either requirement.

```py
query1 = {'$and':[
    
        {"$expr": {
            "$lt": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$period_ending" }}, datetime.strptime('20180331', "%Y%m%d") ]
        }},
        {"is_dormant": {'$eq':True}}
    ]
}

query2 = {'$and':[
    
        {"$expr": {
            "$gt": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$period_ending" }}, datetime.strptime('20200331', "%Y%m%d") ]
        }},
        {"is_dormant": {'$eq':False}}
    ]
}

query_comb = {'$or': [
        query1,
        query2
    ]
}

documents = filed_accounts.find(query_comb)
documents = [d for d in documents]
```

`documents` correctly contains the documents for `"uniqueid1"`, `"uniqueid2"`, `"uniqueid4"`, and `"uniqueid5"` which pertain to registration numbers `"0001"`, `"0002"`, `"0001"` again, and `"0004"`.

But instead of returning all documents that meet either query, I want to return just the registration number that is the union of both queries. Ideally, for this example, it should return `regno` `"0001"` as that is the only entity that was dormant before March 31st 2018 and not dormant after Match 31st 2020.

I am very new to MongoDB and pymongo and the complexity of facets and aggregates for similar solutions has me confused. An explanation for my specific situation would go a long way.

(Ideally, I would actually want to return all documents with that same registration number, not just the number itself, but I can submit a second query for that if I have to.)